# libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed (Centos 7 error)

Tags: c++, c, linux, centos, libstdc++

I upgraded the GCC version on my centos 7 server from 4.x to 7.x.
I tried compiling/building my application which went fine , and then I created an RPM containing a shared library to deploy.

However, when trying to install this RPM, I get the following error

"libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed "

I understand that this implies that the libstdc++.so.6 needs to be updated, but I am not sure how, or whether it is the right approach.

Can someone kindly share some information on this issue , and how to resolve this ?

regards
Tej

Comment: This error cannot occur if you really compiled and built your application on the same server. This error means that the binary the application was linked with does not exist. Since the application was compiled on the same server, and especially because this is the standard C++ library, it logically means that the library must exist. The most likely answer is that you did not compile any source code, and you simply built a thin wrapper for some third party vendor's binary blob.

Comment: Hi Sam
Thanks for the quick reply. However, I am sure that the application is getting compiled and generated correctly.

1) If I compile the application with gcc 4.8.x instead of gcc 7.x, the application seems to be fine. The RPM is built and I am able to install it without issues.

Comment: Hi Sam
Thanks for the quick reply. However, I am sure that the application is getting compiled and generated correctly.

1) If I compile the application with gcc 4.8.x instead of gcc 7.x, the application seems to be fine. The RPM is built and I am able to install it without issues.

The weird issue is that, when I try to compile the application using gcc 7.x, it gets built. But however, while installing with RPM, it fails 

Btw, as a dependency in the RPM, is the term "gcc-c++" correct ? or does it have to be something else ?

Comment: Did you build gcc 7.x itself and install it as an rpm?

Comment: The new gcc 7.x must have a `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.24` somewhere. Point to the new libstdc++.so.6 : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[path]:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [executable]`

Comment: Hi Sam/Knud

Yes, I built the gcc 7.x from source and did a "make" , "make install"
I presume this would have installed the libstdc++.so.6.0.24 (correct me if I am wrong)

I had a couple of questions that may seem elementary (pls bear with me)

1) Does g++ know automatically whether to link against libstdc++.so.6.0.19 or against 6.0.24 , depending on which g++ is used ?

2) My RPM has a dependency "gcc-c++". However, the gcc-c++ installed on my system is 4.8.x
Is that a reason why the "libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed" error occurs ?

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Find a library or an executable binary file in your RPM that requires GLIBCXX_3.4.20 and rebuild it with new compiler.